# How to set Boolean value to an 'Yes' or 'No' h:selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf-2

I have the following code in JSF-2 Mojarra 2.0.8 running on Tomcat 7

```
<h:panelGrid  id="yesNoRadioGrid">
<h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{user.yesNoRadioGridFlag}">
    <h:outputText id ="otherLbl" value="Select Yes or No"></h:outputText>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="yesNoRadio" value ="#{user.yesNoRadio}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{user.choices}"/>                    
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="userDetailsGrid "></f:ajax>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>      
<h:message for ="yesNoRadio"> </h:message>
<h:panelGrid  id="userDetailsGrid">
<h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{user.yesNoRadio}">
    <h:outputLabel>Name :</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="customerName" value="#{user.customerName}"></h:inputText>
    <h:outputLabel>Salary: </h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="customerSalary" value="#{user.customerSalary}"></h:inputText>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

My managedBean contain following

```
private enum Choice {

    Yes, No; 
    } 
private Choice yesNoRadio;
public Choice[] getChoices() {
    return Choice.values(); 
    }
public Choice getYesNoRadio() {
    return yesNoRadio;
}
public void setYesNoRadio(Choice yesNoRadio) {
    this.yesNoRadio = yesNoRadio;
}
```

How can I render my 'userDetailsGrid' based on the boolean value (user.yesNoRadio) selected in

I found a workarround by adding following in my mangedbean

```
private Boolean yesNoRadio;
public SelectItem[] getMyBooleanValues() {   
    return new SelectItem[] {    
    new SelectItem(Boolean.TRUE, "Yes"),   
    new SelectItem(Boolean.FALSE, "No")    
    };   
}
```

and changing my view to

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="yesNoRadio" value ="#{user.yesNoRadio}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{user.myBooleanValues}" />                   
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="userDetailsGrid "></f:ajax>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also just check the enum value in the `rendered` attribute. Enums are evaluated as strings in EL, so you can do a simple string comparison. This way you can keep your original code.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{user.yesNoRadio == 'Yes'}">
```

By the way, you perhaps really want to use `execute="@this"` instead of `execute="@form"` (or just remove it altogether, it defaults to `@this` already). The `execute="@form"` will process the *entire* form and thus also fire validation there where you perhaps don't want.

Comment: Yes..thats what I was looking for. Thanks BalusC. I am new to JSF and really appreciate your comments on the usage of execute attribute. One question , I  have got command button and in which  I don't want the validation get fired, So I've removed the execute attribute from the command button, but the action event didn't fire in that situation. What could be the reason?.

Answer (score 16):

Use a simple Boolean value in your backing bean:

```
private Boolean choice;
// getter and setter
```

And in the facelet:

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="yesNoRadio" value ="#{user.choice}">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}" itemLabel="No" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}" itemLabel="Yes"/>
  <f:ajax execute="@form" render="userDetailsGrid "></f:ajax>
</h:selectOneRadio>
..
<h:panelGrid  id="userDetailsGrid">
  <h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{user.choice}">
  ..
  </h:panelGrid>
  ..
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt ! , I feel the view is getting bit bulky with those direct boolean vlues and each select items. Do you see any possible drawbacks in the workarround mentioned above with the help of a public SelectItem[] getMyBooleanValues().