# Type-appropriate searching in dropdowns and search boxes in frontend

Tags: jsf, converters

I have used custom converter classes with annotations like `@FacesConverter(forClass = Date.class)` to override the JSF default string representation of Date and Boolean objects in the frontend. I have two problems with this:

- Date works as expected – all Date objects have a consistent representation in the frontend. However, Boolean works only if I change the annotation to `@FacesConverter("mypackage.presentation.BooleanFormatConverter")` and then explicitly invoke it in my xhtml, each time I want to use it, as `<f:converter converterId="mypackage.presentation.BooleanFormatConverter" />`.
- I am changing the string representation of booleans to Yes/No, and I have filter boxes on boolean columns on my datatable with those string values. However, it does not seem to recognise that the string values correspond to the boolean true/false. I don't know how to fix this without explicitly changing the type of the booleans to string in the backend, then treating those as string columns in my datatable (and for other reasons, I'd rather keep types distinct and avoid explicitly converting everything to a string in the backend).

Comment: Why do you need a converter for a dropdown representation of a boolean? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187574/how-to-set-boolean-value-to-an-yes-or-no-hselectoneradio

Comment: I want the string representation to be "Yes"/"No" rather than "true"/"false", like in the question you link to. However, when I read that solution's workaround, it seems to me that I'd need to create a separate explicit Boolean value in my backing bean for each column. This seems excessive, as I have a large number of Boolean columns in my table.

I'm using a dropdown rather than radio button because I want it to be possible to toggle true/false/both.

Comment: totally wrong... use labels on the select. All plain and simple like in the 16 upvoted answer

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple in the end, following Kukeltje's suggestion: a boolean in the backing bean (which does not need to be done per-column) and changing the xhtml:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{myView.yesNoCheckbox}" label="Select" onchange="PF('tableE').filter()" scrollHeight="150" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{true}" itemLabel="Yes"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{false}" itemLabel="No" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

the only disadvantage is that this part must be done manually per column (my datatable has an obscene number of columns, which is why I wanted a simple global way of doing this, such as a converter).

Comment: Then you would have to add an explicit converter in all the places... much of a muchness imo